# UWP: Is it possible to create your own network files (similar to Onedrive)?

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

I was looking at the documentation for [Determining availability of Microsoft OneDrive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-determining-availability-of-microsoft-onedrive-files) and I was wondering whether is possible to create these kind of files yourself. In other words, is it possible to create network files that can be automatically downloaded or synced by your application, or is this feature reserved for OneDrive?

I couldn't find anything about this myself and I'm assuming the latter, but I was hoping others could provide more insight on this topic.

Comment: it is possible, but it could be way more complicated than you wish.. after all box, googledrive managed it

Comment: Sure it's possible. Like it is possible to create your own message queuing system, your own database system, your own operating system, your own encryption algorythm, your own communication protocol, etc, etc. The big question is if it's worth the effort, and if you really think you can achieve the same level of quality as existing solutions when it comes to the important properties of such systems.

Comment: You implement a [cloud filter provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt827575(v=vs.85).aspx). This is decidedly nontrivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Windows 10 Creators Update Microsoft provides [Cloud Sync Engine / Cloud Filter API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-files-api-portal). It supports all features that OneDrive has: download (hydration), synchronization, offline mode, and commands in Win File Manager. Some API is available via .NET, but most are Win32 API.

Here are examples on GitHub:

- [CloudMirror sample in C++](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror).
- [Virtual File System sample in C#](https://github.com/ITHit/UserFileSystemSamples/tree/master/Windows/VirtualFileSystem).

Cloud Filter API provides several modes, some of which are not for OneDrive-like disk. Here some general principles, so you do not need to test and understand all modes:

1. Create your storage using [StorageProviderSyncRootInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootinfo) with [PopulationPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootinfo.populationpolicy) set to [StorageProviderPopulationPolicy.Full](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageproviderpopulationpolicy). Then your callbacks will be called when an application is trying to list folder content or read file content.
2. During the first folder listing create placeholders inside [CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_callback_type). Disable on-demand population when the initial folder listing is completed. Do NOT update placeholders inside this callback. It looks like it is designed for initial placeholder creation only.
3. When any file/folder is created/updated/deleted/moved/renamed on the server, notify the client via web sockets or other technology (push) and update client placeholders accordingly. Alternatively you can pull the server or implement other sync algorithms.